# boost asio - exclusive binding to the network port

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I develop server app using boost asio. App works great. What doesn't work, is the the exclusive binding to the network port.

I launch one instance of the app - it starts listening to incoming connections.

I launch one more instance - it also starts listening to incoming connections on the same port. Handler that passed to `async_accept` do not invoked with error as expected.

Usually I just try to acquire the port. If operation fails - port is in use. With Asio this approach does not work. How to check availability of the port?

```
void TcpServerFactory::acceptConnectionsOnPort(int serverPort,
                                               boost::shared_ptr<TcpConfigServerReceiver> tcpConfig,
                                               boost::function<void(boost::shared_ptr<TcpServer>)> onSuccessfullyConnectedHandler)
{
    // todo check is port not busy
    FORMATTED_LOG(this->_log, info) << "Start to accept connections on port " << serverPort;
    auto endpoint = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), serverPort);
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor> tcpAcceptor(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(this->_ioService, endpoint));

    this->acceptConnections(tcpAcceptor, tcpConfig, onSuccessfullyConnectedHandler);
}

void TcpServerFactory::acceptConnections(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor> tcpAcceptor,
                                         boost::shared_ptr<TcpConfigServerReceiver> tcpConfig,
                                         boost::function<void(boost::shared_ptr<TcpServer>)> onSuccessfullyConnectedHandler)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> tcpSocket(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(this->_ioService));
    boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code &)> onAcceptOperationCompletedHandler =
        boost::bind(&TcpServerFactory::onAcceptOperationCompleted, this->downcasted_shared_from_this<TcpServerFactory>(),
                    _1, tcpAcceptor, tcpSocket, tcpConfig, onSuccessfullyConnectedHandler);

    tcpAcceptor.get()->async_accept(*tcpSocket, onAcceptOperationCompletedHandler);
}

void TcpServerFactory::onAcceptOperationCompleted(const boost::system::error_code & err,
                                                  boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor> tcpAcceptor,
                                                  boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> tcpSocket,
                                                  boost::shared_ptr<TcpConfigServerReceiver> tcpConfig,
                                                  boost::function<void(boost::shared_ptr<TcpServer>)> onSuccessfullyConnectedHandler)
{
    if (err)
    {
        FORMATTED_LOG(this->_log, info) << "Failed to accept connections on port " << tcpAcceptor->local_endpoint().port() << "due to error " << BOOST_ERROR_TO_STREAM(err);
        return;
    }
    this->acceptConnections(tcpAcceptor, tcpConfig, onSuccessfullyConnectedHandler);
    this->onConnectionEstablished(tcpSocket, tcpConfig, onSuccessfullyConnectedHandler);
}
```

**Update**

I tried to replace constructor of acceptor on series of commands. I expected that on `tcpAcceptor->bind()` exception will be raised, but that didn't happened.

```
// boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor> tcpAcceptor(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(this->_ioService, endpoint));


boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor> tcpAcceptor(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(this->_ioService));
tcpAcceptor->open(endpoint.protocol());
tcpAcceptor->set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
tcpAcceptor->bind(endpoint);
boost::system::error_code err;
tcpAcceptor->listen(boost::asio::socket_base::max_connections, err);
```

Answer (score 0):

`reuse_address` is not supposed to do that. Its meaning to avoid "wait" interval after port was freed.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I misunderstood docs about `reuse_address`. But how to check availability of the port with Asio?

Comment: @VictorMezrin you will get `asio::error::address_in_use` exception when trying to bind() it.

Comment: I use this constructor of acceptor: `http://goo.gl/QLoR2L` (overload 3). According to the docs internally it calls `acceptor.bind()`, but exception not raised. I tried to replace constructor with series of commands (look at update of the question) - that doesn't work too :(